# Zoo Visitor forgot password form redirecting

Tags: zoo-visitor

I'm trying to create a forgot-password form on my site where Zoo Visitor is used to manage members, however, when adding the standard form code from the examples provided I cannot access the form url, I'm getting a 302 redirect back to my login page (I've no redirects set in my htaccess)

linking to {site_url}members/forgot-password

members/forgot-password template code:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password error_handling="inline" reset_url="/members/reset_password" parse="inward"}
    {if password_sent}
        <h3>
            A password reset mail has been sent to the provided email.
        </h3>
    {if:else}
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="email" class="form-label">
                    Your email:
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-text" value="" />
            </p>
            {error:email}
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Retrieve password" class="button" />
        </p>
    {/if}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took a peak at one of my production sites, and I have a password reset like that, but the `reset_url` parameter points to a different page... the actual password reset request (where an email gets sent) and the page it links to (the page where they can actually reset their password) need to be different pages (probably not **need** to, be easier to manage that way).

Here is an example:

**Password reset request page** /account/password

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password error_handling="inline" reset_url="account/reset_password" parse="inward" class="forms"}
    {if password_sent}
        A password reset email has been sent to the provided email.
    {if:else}
        Password Reset
        <br>
        Enter your Email address to receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password.
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="64" >
        </label>
        <label class="error">
            {error:email}
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" value="Get Password Reset Email" class="btn width-100" />
        </label>
        Please make sure to check your "Spam" folder if you don't receive the password reset email.
    {/if}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password}
```

**Password reset page** /account/reset_password

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:reset_password error_handling="inline" class="forms"}
    {if password_reset}
        Your password has been reset. You can now login with your new password.
        <a href="{site_url}/login">
            Login
        </a>
    {if:else}
        Password reset
        <label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password" id="new_password" class="width-100" required/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="password" name="password_confirm" placeholder="New Password Again" id="new_password_confirm" class="width-100" required/>
        </label>
        <label class="error">
            {error:password}
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset your password" class="btn width-100" />
        </label>
    {/if}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:reset_password}
```

Also, I'm not sure about your setup, but is your native EE member url set to `/members`? That could be messing with Zoo Visitor. I don't remember enough about the plugin to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks @jrothafer. I'm using pretty much identical code to yourself, I also have the same reset password form. I've tried changing the template group to account also but to no avail. Emails are not being sent out at all.

Comment: ??? Your question says nothing about emails, just the strange redirect. Had something changed?

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the original post, email notifications also arent being sent out, the forgot password template is never reached due to the redirect